# Satellizer: Cannot get data for any email besides my own

Tags: angularjs, node.js, authentication, satellizer

Right, now I cloned this repo's authentication demo and hosted it locally.

https://satellizer.herokuapp.com/#/
https://github.com/sahat/satellizer

I connected it to my school email google OAuth2 clientID. For some reason, I cannot get the profile data for my gmail accounts besides my school email(developer email).

The official satellizer demo does in fact work for all my gmail accounts.

Since, **the code is exactly the same** for my locally hosted demo and the official. I need help trouble shooting what the issue is.

- 1) Would it be the fault of my Google OAuth2 setup?
- 2) Is the fact
  its locally hosted screwing it up?
- 3) MongoDB error?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem? I am also facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

@Devendera,

It was a MongoDB problem. I solved it by getting the local database, and dumping the user collections.